# Compress empty folders as folders, not files

Tags: powershell, compression, system

I use System.IO.Compression.FileSystem to compress a folder with subfolders in a powershell script.
Some of the folders are empty, and it creates empty files instead of empty folders.
I thought this was a bug, but they specify it in their [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile.createfromdirectory?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_Compression_ZipFile_CreateFromDirectory_System_String_System_String_System_IO_Compression_CompressionLevel_System_Boolean_):

> The directory structure from the file system is preserved in the
>   archive. If the directory is empty, an empty archive is created. Use
>   this method overload to specify the compression level and whether to
>   include the base directory in the archive.

Do you know how to avoid this, I want the empty folders as folders... That seems ridiculous...

**EDIT:**

```
$compressionLevel = [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Optimal
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($Source, $Target, $compressionLevel, $true)
```

Comment: Hmmm ... I'm not sure if i got you right. If you compress something - no matter what it is - it will result in an archive FILE, like archive.zip for example. And if you compress an empty folder this empty folder will end up in such an archive file. Have you considered using the built in cmdlet [Compress-Archive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive?view=powershell-5.1)?

Comment: Could you please include a snippet of exactly how you're executing the compression? It will help us test and troubleshoot with you.

Comment: @root done, it so simple i thought was't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

For me it works just fine if I add a reference to the `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll`:

```
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IO.Compression.FileSystem\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll'

# compress using just two parameters. 
# This will omit the source folder and gives you no option to set the CompressionLevel
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory("D:\Testzip", "D:\result.zip")
```

If you want the sourcefolder included aswell, use the function with 4 parameters:

```
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory("D:\Testzip", "D:\result.zip", "Fastest", $true)
```

See [CompressionLevel Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.compressionlevel?view=netframework-4.7.2)

For testing I used a folder structure where only subfolder `D:\Testzip\folder1\folder1-1` is empty:

> ```
> D:\TESTZIP
> |   the only file in the root directory.txt
> |
> \---folder1
>     +---folder1-1
>     \---folder1-2
>             just a single file here.txt
> ```

The `result.zip` file afterwards included the empty folder just fine..

Comment: This is a good compromise solution, but I need the Optimal level. Otherwise file is too heavy.

Comment: @toscanelli That is why I added the link to [Compression Level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.compressionlevel?view=netframework-4.7.2). Simply change `"Fastest"` to `"Optimal"`

Comment: Ah, sorry, I understood that the trick was reduce the compression level. I see you add a reference manually. I added without full path (Add-Type -Assembly System.IO.Compression.FileSystem), because I won't know which OS will be run on (Windows for sure, but don't know the version...).
I will try anyway.

Comment: This is great, but you can simplify the AddType to `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem`